# How to make relate field as Dropdown - SuiteCRM Version 7.10.4 Sugar Version 6.5.25 (Build 344)

Tags: sugarcrm, suitecrm

I am trying to make a dropdown by fetching values from the relate module, I tried the following, In the path i have added the code as mentioned below.

> Custom/Extension/Modules/mymodule/Ext/Vardefs/vardefs.php

```
$dictionary['mymodule']['fields']['custom_field'] = array(
'name' => 'custom_field',
'dbType' => 'non-db',
'source' => 'non-db',
'type' => 'relate',
'vname' => 'LBL_CUSTOM_TYPE',
'link' => 'accounts',
'module' => 'Accounts',
'rname' => 'account_type',
'studio' => 'visible',
);
```

but not working, anything i am missing. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked for me, add **myfield.php** file
 path:

> \custom\Extension\modules\yourModule\Ext\Vardefs\myfield.php

code:

```
<?php 

$dictionary["myModule"]["fields"]["myfield"] = array (
    'required' => true,
    'name' => 'myfield',
    'vname' => 'Select',
    'type' => 'enum',
    'required' => false,
    'massupdate' => 0,
    'comments' => '',
    'help' => '',
    'importable' => 'true',
    'duplicate_merge' => 'disabled',
    'duplicate_merge_dom_value' => '0',
    'audited' => false,
    'reportable' => true,
    'len' => 70,
    'size' => '20',
    'function' => 'getList',
);

?>
```

In vardef i called a function 'getlist'

and create **getlist.php** in path:

> \custom\Extension\application\Ext\Utils\getlist.php

code:

```
 <?php 
function getlistvalues(){
    static $listvalues = null;
    if(!$listvalues){
        global $db;
        $query = "SELECT id,name  FROM lm_leave_admin order by name asc ";
        $result = $db->query($query, false);
        $listvalues = array();
        $listvalues[''] = '';
        while (($row = $db->fetchByAssoc($result)) != null) {
            $listvalues[$row['id']] = $row['name'];
        }
    }
    return $listvalues;
} 
?>
```

And finally make a Quick Repair and Rebuild to see the changes.
**

> Reference: https://community.sugarcrm.com/thread/21298

**